# Is there any way to turn off pop-up UI windows (dialogues)?

Tags: interface

One of the UI changes in Blender 2.8 (I'm on 2.83.5) vs. 2.7 seems to be that, apparently, the one-window (no pop-up/ dialogue window) policy in the UI design seems to have been abandoned.

To give an example: previously, bringing up the save dialog with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (now <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) would show the save view, which would simply replace the contents of the entire Blender Window. Doing this now, Blender will spawn an additional window for the save dialogue, with the main window remaining in the background.

Is there any way to turn this pop-up window behavior off and essentially revert to the 2.7 behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found how to do this for the *Render* and *File Browser* (applies to the save dialogue) windows: `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Interface` > `Editors` > `Temporary Windows`.

However, this does not prevent the preferences window itself from opening up as a new window, so this doesn't *fully* answer the question.

Comment: Hello :). It's your choice whether to open it in a new window through *Edit > Preferences* or as an editor window through *Editor Type dropdown > Preferences* (the dropdown that changes 3D Viewport/Shader editor/Outliner/...).

Comment: @JachymMichal interesting, didn't know that. However, that means manually changing my UI and then changing it back after I'm done with the options. Would prefer to just tell Blender "never open anything in a separate window, just like you did in 2.7" and be done with it. Maybe that's not possible anymore.